# [Polymer Template]: Check if `<content>` exist

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

There is a way to check if `<content>` exist from LightDOM? I don't want to use a prop for this (or i should do?), i think about something like:

```
<template is="dom-if" if="CONTENT">
    <content></content>
</template>
<template is="dom-if" if="!CONTENT">
    <p>PLACEHOLDER</p>
</template>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<my-element>
   <div></div>
</my-element>

<!-- NO CONTENT -->
<my-element></my-element>
```

**EDIT**
Solved by switching to the new `<slot>`element.

Comment: doesn't this work: `<content><p>PLACEHOLDER</p></content>`? I know that works for the new `<slot>` element.

Comment: @Supersharp It doesn't work.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to use a prop :-/

Comment: So i have to pass a property ex `content=true` when content is passed through the LightDOM?


**EDIT** I should start using <slot> instead of <template>

Comment: I solved by switching to the new <slot> element. Thank you @Supersharp

Comment: Could you please share your final solution?

Comment: The shadow dom v1 spec tell you to use the <slot> element to get children from the light dom. The content inside the <slot> element is used as placeholder when no children are passed through. <slot>Im a placeholder</slot>